# Fortran to C interface: Why does doing it right mess everything up?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, interface, fortran

I have alot to learn about Fortran/C interfacing.  In a toy code I'm working with, I use C to allocate a double precision array (pointer, actually) for Fortran:

```
double precision, pointer :: arr(:)
type(C_PTR) :: p
integer :: L=50000
p = alloc_for_fortran(L)
call c_f_pointer(p, arr, [L])
```

(`alloc_for_fortran` is a C function I wrote.  Seems to work OK.  I can show it, but I thought I would try to keep out irrelevant code to keep this post as short as I can.)

I have a simple C function that just gives the element of an array:

```
void examine(double *arr, int *whichone) {
        printf("contents: %lf\n", arr[*whichone-1]);
}
```

This works fine *if I don't define* an interface in the Fortran code.  For instance, this code

```
arr(1) = 5.3
examine(arr,1)
```

gives output:

```
contents: 5.300000
```

Now I define an interface for `examine`, like I'm "supposed" to:

```
interface
subroutine examine(arr, i) bind(C, name="examine")
            use iso_c_binding
            double precision, pointer :: arr(:)
            integer :: i
end subroutine
end interface
```

And now the output is incorrect:

```
contents: 0.000000
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What will probably fix the error is omitting ", pointer" from the interface. Why do you think you need the pointer attribute for the double precision argument, and not need one for the integer one? Once I have cooked dinner I might add a proper answer, but that's probably the main issue, though there is at least one other as well.

Comment: @IanBush  Sensible comment, but it doesn't change the output.  Thanks just the same.  BTW, `arr` is a Fortran pointer, but `i` is just an integer.

Comment: `whichone` and `i` are integer indexes that can be passed by value, yes? No need for a pointer.  The array is a different story, and I am a no-nothing wrt fortran.

Comment: Well please show a minimal, complete example then.

Comment: @jwdonahue   My understanding is that Fortran actually passes pointers, not values.  So the receiving C function has to dereference them.  But I am fully willing to be corrected by anyone who knows better.

Comment: @bob.sacamento, oh I definitely make no claims to know better.

Comment: For the dummy argument to be deferred or assumed shape array you need to use Fortran 2018 interoperability, rather than Fortran 2003 as is possible for explicit shape or assumed size. As your C code isn't interoperating in the F2018 way, the `pointer` attribute is wrong (and you can't get around that with `arr(:)` instead of `arr(*)`. Do you need the array to be deferred or assumed shape?

Comment: That is, is `double precision :: arr(*)` what you are wanting? (Or rather `real(c_double) :: arr(*)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it. Unless you supply a  [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to say much more. The main errors in what is shown are trying to pass a Fortran pointer to a C one, when standard Fortran argument mechanisms are sufficient, and declaring the C dummy argument as an assumed shape array, when you should use assumed size as C doesn't support the more advanced Fortran feature

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat examine.c
#include <stdio.h>

void examine(double *arr, int *whichone) {
        printf("contents: %lf\n", arr[*whichone-1]);
}
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat use_examine.f90
Program use_examine

  Use iso_c_binding, Only : c_double, c_int
  
  Implicit None

  Interface
     Subroutine examine( arr, i ) bind( C, name = 'examine' )
       Use iso_c_binding, Only : c_double, c_int
  
       Implicit None
       Real   ( c_double ), Dimension( * ), Intent( In ) :: arr
       Integer( c_int )                   , Intent( In ) :: i
     End Subroutine examine
  End Interface

  Real( c_double ), Pointer, Dimension( : ) :: a

  Allocate( a( 1:2 ) )
  a( 1 ) = 5.3_c_double

  Call examine( a, 1_c_int )
  
End Program use_examine
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 examine.c
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran  -c -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -std=f2008 use_examine.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran use_examine.o examine.o
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
contents: 5.300000
```

Comment: C can interoperate with assumed shape and deferred shape Fortran arrays

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the new stuff in 2018 - haven't studied or used it. Will edit to correct at some point.